# How to select value from this dropdown list in Selenium using C# e.g. Main Feature as shown in the attached picture

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

Website if you want to try by your self: https://phptravels.com/ to run the script

```html
<div class="lvl-0 dropdown">
  <span>Features</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content featuresDropdown">
    <a class="lvl-1 link nav-link" href="https://phptravels.com/features">Main Features</a>
    <a class="lvl-1 link nav-link" href="https://phptravels.com/hotels-module-features/">Hotels Module</a>
    <a class="lvl-1 link nav-link" href="https://phptravels.com/flights-module-features/">Flights Module</a>
    <a class="lvl-1 link nav-link" href="https://phptravels.com/tours-module-features/">Tours Module</a>
    <a class="lvl-1 link nav-link" href="https://phptravels.com/cars-module-features/">Cars Module</a>
    <a class="lvl-1 link nav-link" href="https://phptravels.com/offers-module-features/">Offers Module</a>
    <a class="lvl-1 link nav-link" href="https://phptravels.com/blog-module-features/">Blog Module</a>
    <a class="lvl-1 link nav-link" href="https://phptravels.com/newsletter-module-features/">Newsletter Module</a>
    <a class="lvl-1 link nav-link" href="https://phptravels.com/cms-module-features/">CMS Module</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```java
public void featureButton()
{
    Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);
    IWebElement dropdown = webDriver.FindElement(POM.mainfeature);
    IWebElement option = webDriver.FindElement(POM.Option);
    Actions hoverClick = builder.MoveToElement(dropdown).Click(option).Click();
    hoverClick.Build().Perform();
   
    WaitTime();

}

public void WaitTime()
{
    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
}

public static class POM
{

    public static By mainfeature = By.XPath("//*[@class=\"lvl-0 dropdown\"]");
    public static By Option = By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'Main Features')]");
}
```

---

```
ERROR[
 Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:54020/session/a4d224f68515fa2eba6289d48ae17d71/url timed out after 60 seconds.
      ----> System.Net.WebException : The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
  Stack Trace: 
    HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
    HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
    DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
    RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
    RemoteNavigator.GoToUrl(String url)
    LogInTest.Test() line 29
    --WebException
    HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
    HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for adding the screenshot. Could you please also add the code you have tried, and the full error message you receive?

Comment: I added everything, waiting for your kind response

Comment: Which line of your code is giving the error?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the web element by its link text of "Main Features".

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Main Features"));
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts and giving me time, I added everything... you can check it. It's still show me the error

Answer (score 1):

its hard to understand without screen shot and which one of the element is a dropdown button and what are the option.

if its a dropdown that gets displayed on click then use:

```
WebDriver.FindElement( By.Xpath( "//*[@class=\"lvl-0 dropdown\"]")).click();      
WebDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Main Features")).click();
```

If its a dropdown that works with hover then use :

```
Actions builder = new Actions( WebDriver );
IWebElement dropdown=  WebDriver.FindElement( By.Xpath( "//*[@class=\"lvl-0 dropdown\"]"));   
IWebElement option= WebDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Main Features"));   
Actions hoverClick = builder.MoveToElement(dropdown).click(option).Click();
hoverClick.Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Main Features"} 
Display me this error

Comment: @Khan try `//*[contains(text(),"Main Features")]`